# Most efficient algorithm to read an optical quadrature encoder in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio, rospy

I'm working on a project where I use PD control for 3 motors with optical quadrature encoders and efficiency is a must, because I don't want to lose some counts and ruin the positioning.

First, I created a class called CMotor, where i define some attributes and methods. Among the methods, I defined RotaryDeal, which is in charge of dealing with the counts.

At the beginning it looked like this:

```
class CMotor:
    def RotaryDeal(self):
        self.LastB = GPIO.input(self.PinB)
        self.LastA = GPIO.input(self.PinA)

        while (self.LastA==GPIO.input(self.PinA) and self.LastB==GPIO.input(self.PinB) ):
                    flag = 1

        self.CurrentB = GPIO.input(self.PinB)
        self.CurrentA = GPIO.input(self.PinA)

        if self.CurrentA:
            if self.CurrentB:
                if self.LastA:
                    self.Cuentas-=1
                else:
                    self.Cuentas+=1

            else:
                if self.LastA:
                    self.Cuentas+=1
                else:
                    self.Cuentas-=1

        else:
            if self.CurrentB:
                if self.LastA:
                    self.Cuentas-=1
                else:
                    self.Cuentas+=1

            else:
                if self.LastA:
                    self.Cuentas+=1
                else:
                    self.Cuentas-=1
        print 'Cuentas %s = %d' % (self.Nombre, self.Cuentas)

#(Cuentas is Counts btw)
```

And to use it, I import this file and create an object called M3. Then:

```
try:
    while 1:
        M3.RotaryDeal()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Nevertheless, my code was not efficient and failed to work with multiple motors and also became very unefficient while using rospy. That's why I tried using add_event_detect as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439475/faster-quadrature-decoder-loops-with-python-code)

I finally got something like this:

```
class CMotor:

    #Some other functions and the __init__

    def RotaryDeal(self, ev = None):
            self.CurrentB = GPIO.input(self.PinB)
            self.CurrentA = GPIO.input(self.PinA)

            if self.CurrentA:
                    if self.CurrentB:
                            if self.LastA:
                                    self.Cuentas-=1
                            else:
                                    self.Cuentas+=1

                    else:
                            if self.LastA:
                                    self.Cuentas+=1
                            else:
                                    self.Cuentas-=1

            else:
                    if self.CurrentB:
                            if self.LastA:
                                    self.Cuentas-=1
                            else:
                                    self.Cuentas+=1

                    else:
                            if self.LastA:
                                    self.Cuentas+=1
                            else:
                                    self.Cuentas-=1
            self.LastA = self.CurrentA
            self.LastB = self.CurrentB

            print 'Cuentas %s = %d' % (self.Nombre, self.Cuentas)

#sorry for the indentation, im copying it from the terminal (using ubuntu mate)
```

And called it like this:

```
try:
    GPIO.add_event_detect(M3.PinA, GPIO.BOTH, callback=M3.RotaryDeal)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(M3.PinB, GPIO.BOTH, callback=M3.RotaryDeal)
        while 1:
            pass
except KeyBoardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Eventhough it's supposed to be more efficient, it did exactly the opposite. When i tried to turn it I got completely different results from the original one. It's supposed to read 3200 counts per revolution if you read the whole 4 situations, but the "efficient" algorithm was losing all my counts. Also, the faster I spinned the rotor, the more counts it missed.

Please, if there is a way more efficent way to read the count with all four situations of the encoder or I'm comitting an error my self, i would be more than thankful to if you post it.

PD.: For those who don't get what i meant for 4 situations:

```
 |PinA|PinB|
1| 0  | 0  |
2| 0  | 1  |
3| 1  | 0  |
4| 1  | 1  |
```

PD 2: Im going to use rospy and send this counts to topic, and the process of publishing consumes some time so i need the code to be as efficient as posible

Answer (score 0):

Is this making a print statement every time RotaryDeal() is executed? Printing to terminal is a surprisingly slow operation, it may be best to simply store your encoder values in a local variable and print it every few thousand iterations or so.